# validate the number of numeric characters loaded python

Tags: python

I've been trying to solve this simple puzzle for hours, I'm new to python and the idea with this function is to be able to validate that the input corresponds to a numerical value and that otherwise restart the system, I can't get the function to return the value as it should and That is why I ask for your collaboration, without further ado, thank you very much.

```
import json
def cantidad_alumnos_cargar():
  try:
    a = int(input("Cantidad de alumnos a cargar: "))
    return a
  except:
    print("pone numeros!")
    cantidad_alumnos_cargar()

print(cantidad_alumnos_cargar())
```

Comment: similiar to [asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: If i int first por example and "a", then return "none"


Cantidad de alumnos a cargar: a
pone numeros!
Cantidad de alumnos a cargar: 2
None

Answer (score 0):

```py
import json
def cantidad_alumnos_cargar():
    try:
        a = input(int("Cantidad de alumnos a cargar: "))
        return a
    except:
        print("pone numeros!")
        cantidad_alumnos_cargar()
    
    print(cantidad_alumnos_cargar())
```

You should be calling `input()` then `int()`, not `int()` then `input()`.

Comment: Did you try running this code? Note how you are trying to pass a string which is not of an integer. This would immediately raise a `ValueError`, since any string passed to `int()` must be that of a base-10 integer.

Comment: recursive makes no sense here.